# Silverlight datagrid cell edit does not reflect in cell

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, cell, edit

In this silverlight grid cell, the display value does not update when the edit value is updated, any ideas why?

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bid Qty" IsReadOnly="True">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource CustomDoubleToStringConverter}}" 
                       Foreground="{Binding Path=BidPrice.TextColour}" 
                       ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=BidPrice.ToolTip}" 
                       ToolTipService.Placement="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CustomDoubleToStringConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code (very simplified) :

```
// field is bound to BidPrice on this
    public class PriceStackLine : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        public ProductPrice BidPrice { get; set; }
    }

// BidPrice is a ProductPrice with a Quantity property
    public class ProductPrice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
            private double _qty;
            public double Quantity
            {
                get
                {
                    return _qty;
                }
                set
                {
                    _qty = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


// converter
    public class CustomDoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double num = (double)value;

            if (num == 0)
                return string.Empty;

            return num;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double result = 0;
            double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE - FIXED! The TextColour was null on the new edits which was probably defaulting to transparent, that is why I couldnt see the edit**

Comment: Are you sure that your binding property gets updated? Do you raise PropertyChanged event? Other than that "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" seems irrelevant, do you need it? There also can be some errors in converter. It's better if you share more information on what happens when you debug your application.

Comment: actually, that doesn't mean that property gets updated, it is possible that binding doesn't work at all(even for textbox) and you are just seeing textbox content you put there. Have you tried to set a breakpoint inside Quantity property. Is is being hit when you finish editing in textbox? If it is, what value do you get there?

Comment: @noaRAVE yes just checked and can definately confirm the property is changed. I will also post some code in a minute.

Comment: Wow, that was unexpected =)